# Changing onkeyup function to an IF statement

Tags: javascript

I have a search box to change the class of an image when searched. But it is interfering with other CSS code. I would like the function to run only when 3 characters or max is entered. Been at this for hours.

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="search" size="3" maxlength="3"/>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var input = document.getElementById('search');
var images = document.getElementById("GALLERY").getElementsByTagName('img');

input.onkeyup = function(){
  for(var i = images.length; i--;){
      images[i].className = 
        images[i].src.indexOf(this.value) > 0 ?
        'highlight' :
        '';
  }       
};
```

You can check actual page here http://jsfiddle.net/FZYgP/2/

Comment: You can get the length of the text in the input using `this.value.length` in your function.

Comment: Can `this.value` occur at the beginning of `images[i].src`? If so, you'll probably want `>= 0`, not `> 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
input.onkeyup = function(){
  var value = this.value;
  if(value.length < 3 && value.length < input.getAttribute('maxlength')){
       return;
  }
  for(var i = images.length; i--;){
      images[i].className = 
        images[i].src.indexOf(value) > 0 ?
        'highlight' :
        '';
  }       
};
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sHYQN/)

Comment: @Arun_P_Johny This was very short and helpful, Thank you.